# How to filter out crawler traps in a static corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a homework where we are asked to write a program to crawl a given static corpus. In the output, my code prints all the URLs crawled, but I know there are some that are traps, but I can't think of a way to filter those out in a Pythonic way.

I used regex to filter the tap-like url contents out, but this is not allowed in the homework as it is considered as hard-coding.

https://cbcl.ics.uci.edu/doku.php/software/arem?do=login&sectok=4d26fc0839d47d4ec13c5461c1ed6d96

http://cbcl.ics.uci.edu/doku.php/software/arem?do=login&sectok=d8b984cc6aa00bd1ef20471ac5150094

https://cbcl.ics.uci.edu/doku.php/software/arem?do=login&sectok=d8b984cc6aa00bd1ef20471ac5150094

http://cbcl.ics.uci.edu/doku.php/software/arem?do=login&sectok=d504a3676483838e82f07064ca3e12ee

and more with similar structure. There are also calendar urls with similar structure, only changing days:

http://calendar.ics.uci.edu/calendar.php?type=day&calendar=1&category=&day=22&month=01&year=2017

http://calendar.ics.uci.edu/calendar.php?type=day&calendar=1&category=&day=25&month=01&year=2017

http://calendar.ics.uci.edu/calendar.php?type=day&calendar=1&category=&day=26&month=01&year=2017

http://calendar.ics.uci.edu/calendar.php?type=day&calendar=1&category=&day=27&month=01&year=2017

I want to filter those out of my results but I can't think of any way.

Comment: Try using Request, and just check for the 'status_code', example if the status code is 200, the url is valid

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
    import requests

    for url in urls:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
            response.raise_for_status()
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
        else:
            print('Url is valid!')
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this out. However, the traps that I am looking for are the ones that lead to the same page, while having different queries in their URL. Is it possible to approach from this way? I can't put my code here since it might cause plagiarism later, so I am at a loss.

Comment: @beneficarum Aha, I understand. Can you upload to your question some of those urls?